# Sum Distinct Duplicated Values

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

I have a dataset as below:

```
customer      buy          profit      
   a        laptop          350       
   a        mobile          350       
   b        laptop case     50       
   c        laptop          200       
   c        mouse           200
```

It does not matter how many rows the customer has, the profit is already stated in the row (it's already an accumulative sum). For example, the profit of `customer a` is `350` and the profit of `customer c` is `200`.

I would like to sum uniquely the profit for all the customers so the desire output should be 350 + 50 + 200 = 600. However, I need to execute this in one line of code (without doing subquery, nested query or write in a separate CTE).

I tried with Partition By but cannot combine `MAX` and `SUM` together. I also tried `SUM (DISTINCT)` but it does not work either

```
MAX(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY customer)
```

If anyone could give me a hint on an approach to tackle this, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a subquery here:

```sql
SELECT SUM(profit) AS total_profit
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT customer, profit FROM yourTable) t;
```

By the way, your table design should probably change such that you are not storing the redundant profit per customer across many different records.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `SUM()` window function with `MAX()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(MAX(profit)) OVER () total
FROM tablename
GROUP BY customer;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=083965b75879cd836733ef5b8b779fdd).

Answer (score 0):

Select sum(distinct profit) as sum from Table

Answer (score 0):

You can select max profit of each customer like this:

```
SELECT customer, MAX(profit) AS max_profit
FROM tablename
GROUP BY customer
```

Then you can summarise the result in your code or even in the query as nested queries:

```
SELECT SUM(max_profit) FROM (
    SELECT customer, MAX(profit) AS max_profit
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY customer
) AS temptable
```